# OData Service Slow to Wake Up after not used for a while

Tags: wcf, ipad, iis, odata, application-pool

I have created an Odata service that i use for my IPad application to talk to an SQL Server database. The problem is the first time the odata server is accessed every morning (with no-one using it over night) it takes along time to connect. Once the first connection is connected than all connections are instant after that.

Does anyone know what i need to do to stop this from happening? I dont mind extending the timeout of an app pool if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options

1) Keep app alive simply by making occasional calls (Every 5 mins or so). I generally just write a quick vbs or js file to make this call and schedule a task

or (probably cleaner, but haven't done this yet)

2) See ScottGu's 4.0 approach [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Comment: Hi Mirko, Because Im looking for a quick solution can you give me an example of your first option?